# JQuery clickable table generated from python, pandas to_html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, pandas

I've created tables in python using pandas to_html function and jsonify with great success.

Separately, I've created a simple HTML table with clickable rows (via jquery/javascript... I honestly don't know the difference) that displays the data of the first data point in the row:

```
<table id="my_table">
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#my_table tr").click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
    });     
});
</script>
```

However, when I generate and load a new table using the to_html function and jsonify in python, I can't get the function to work.

I've also been able to properly place the `id="my_table"` tag into the generated table, so it's not missing the id piece.

After an hour of toying with this, I believe the issue is that the scripts are loaded into memory prior to the table being loaded, so when the id is referenced, the script isn't familiar with the new table.

UPDATE:

I've now included `onclick="my_function()"` in the to_html `<table>` tag which now allows me to execute a click function from the new table.  But I need to tweak the code a bit to:

```
function my_function () {
    $("#my_table tr").click( function() {
        var my_data = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        alert(my_data);
    });
}
```

But there is now a curious behavior - the first click shows 0 alerts.  The second click shows 1 alert.  The third click shows 2 alerts, fourth shows 3, ad infinitum.

Anyone know why that may be?

Comment: From your description it seems that `my_function` is running several times. It should run _only once_ after the table is loaded. Every time `my_function` runs, it assigns a new event listener to the click event.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying... will play around with it and let you know!  Thanks.